# Force redirect page on $.ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Suppose i have the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'some_url',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { some: data },
    success: function(data){
        // Success message will be shown.
        window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000);
    },
    failed : function(data){
        // Error message will be shown.
        window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000);
    }
});
```

and on the server side i have something like this:

```
function delete_json(){
    $post = $this->input->post();
    if(!empty($post)){
        // Do something crazy here and return the result as JSON.

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }else{
        // CURRENTLY THIS DOES NOT WORK......
        // IT DOES NOT REDIRECT THE PAGE AS INTENDED
        redirect('some_url', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

How can i force redirect the user to another page if if the ajax call still expecting a result to be returned?

What would be a good approach to this?

Comment: ajax call in async return redirect url via json and redirect in ajax success

Comment: You need to redirect in success function of ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's an AJAX call it won't have a visible impact on the browser. You will have to do the redirect on the client side.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'some_url',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { some: data },
    success: function(data){
        // Success message will be shown.
        if(data.good===true){
          window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000);
        }
        else{
          window.location.href("http://my.url.here");
        }

    },
    failed : function(data){
        // Error message will be shown.
        window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Alex, that's what i thought. I guess i need to do the redirection from client side.